# Error while starting JBoss server

Tags: jboss

I am very new to JBoss. Currently I have a requirement wherein I need to deploy the application (which is already running on Tomcat) on JBoss. I downloaded the JBoss however the directory structure is different in version 7.

I am running the `bin\standalone.conf.bat` file to start the server however I am getting the below error:

```
Calling "C:\Program Files\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\bin\standalone.conf.bat"
===============================================================================

JBoss Bootstrap Environment

JBOSS_HOME: C:\Program Files\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final

JAVA: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_30\bin\java

JAVA_OPTS: -XX:+TieredCompilation -Dprogram.name=standalone.bat -Xms64M -Xmx51
2M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.se
rver.gcInterval=3600000 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.war
ning=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djboss.server.default.c
onfig=standalone.xml

===============================================================================

Unable to set property fileName on class org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.FileHandl
er: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.PropertyConfigurator.configureProperties(Propert
yConfigurator.java:187)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.PropertyConfigurator.configureHandler(PropertyCo
nfigurator.java:312)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigura
tor.java:128)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigura
tor.java:86)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager.readConfiguration(LogManager.java:246
)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager.readConfiguration(LogManager.java:231
)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(LogManager.java:267)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.readPrimordialConfiguration(LogManager.j
ava:265)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.getLogManager(LogManager.java:248)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:225)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger.<init>(LogManager.java:1092)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger.<init>(LogManager.java:1089)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$1.run(LogManager.java:180)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:157)
    at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:275)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\
standalone\log\boot.log (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:194)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.FileHandler.setFile(FileHandler.java:15
2)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.FileHandler.setFileName(FileHandler.jav
a:183)
    ... 21 more
17:11:18,420 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS018704: Could not create server data direct
ory: C:\Program Files\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\data
    at org.jboss.as.server.ServerEnvironment.<init>(ServerEnvironment.java:3
88)
    at org.jboss.as.server.Main.determineEnvironment(Main.java:242)
    at org.jboss.as.server.Main.main(Main.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.run(Module.java:260)
    at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:291)
Press any key to continue . . .
```

How can I resolve the issue and get the server run properly?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using standalone.bat instead of standalone.conf.bat to start JBoss?

Comment: I used standalone.bat however received the same error..

Answer (score 7):

Try running JBoss in **Administrator mode** or give your **JBoss** folder the proper permissions to access the log files mentioned in the error.

Comment: But I checked at the directory structure and no log folder exists at C:\Program Files\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\ standalone.

Comment: Add the folder: `C:\Program Files\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\server\default\log`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using eclipse, starting it in admin mode does the trick, if not you can start you command prompt in admin mode and then run the start up script from there.

To set admin mode:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff431742.aspx