# starting jboss server through eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jboss, eclipse-plugin

I am new to eclipse and JBoss application development. I am trying to start my jboss server from eclipse.
The steps which I carried out are :

1. I installed boss 4 plugins on eclipse kepler
2. I configured the new->server to jboss with jre7

but when I click start the server it gives me exception list : [Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10072726/error-while-starting-jboss-server)

If I start my server by running standalone.bat, it runs successfully. then why it does not run in eclipse?

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You eclipse should be opened in **Admnistrator Mode**.

[More Information](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-eclipse/jboss-and-eclipse)