# Getting error during installation of Jboss

Tags: java, jboss

When I [trying to install and run the Jboss sever it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZ7VG.jpg) showing following error

Java version :- JAVA 1.7.0_79

Can you please suggest what step need to take for server up and running.

> C:\Jboss\bin>standalone
>       Calling "C:\Jboss\bin\standalone.conf.bat"
>       WARNING JBOSS_HOME may be pointing to a different installation - unpredictable results may occur.
>       ===============================================================================
>
> ```
>   JBoss Bootstrap Environment
>
>   JBOSS_HOME: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jboss
>
>   JAVA: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\\bin\java
>
>   JAVA_OPTS: -XX:+TieredCompilation -Dprogram.name=standalone.bat -Xms64M -Xmx512M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djboss.server.default.config=standalone.xml
> ```

```
===============================================================================

Unable to set property fileName on class org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.FileHandler: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.jboss.logmanager.PropertyConfigurator.configureProperties(PropertyConfigurator.java:187)
        at org.jboss.logmanager.PropertyConfigurator.configureHandler(PropertyConfigurator.java:312)
        at org.jboss.logmanager.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:128)
        at org.jboss.logmanager.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:86)
        at org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager.readConfiguration(LogManager.java:246)
        at org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager.readConfiguration(LogManager.java:231)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(LogManager.java:320)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(LogManager.java:318)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager.readPrimordialConfiguration(LogManager.java:318)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager.getLogManager(LogManager.java:300)
        at java.util.logging.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:265)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger.<init>(LogManager.java:1468)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger.<init>(LogManager.java:1466)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager$1.run(LogManager.java:204)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:181)
        at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:275)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jboss\standalone\log\boot.log (Access is denied)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
        at org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.FileHandler.setFile(FileHandler.java:152)
        at org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.FileHandler.setFileName(FileHandler.java:183)
        ... 22 more
15:37:57,141 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
15:37:57,724 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
15:37:57,836 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting
15:37:58,154 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment-mount-provider: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment-mount-provider: JBAS015843: Failed to create temp file provider
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentMountProvider$Factory$ServerDeploymentRepositoryImpl.start(DeploymentMountProvider.java:111) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10072726/error-while-starting-jboss-server

Comment: Would you mind just clarifying your setup? It looks like you're running standalone.bat from "c:\jboss\bin" and you have JBOSS_HOME set to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jboss"? I seem to recall something about it not liking spaces in the path, so I don't know if that's an issue (I might be wrong on that). Another thing might be permissions - does the user running JBoss have full access to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jboss" and subdirectories?